# document.addEventListener sigue activo en un ciclo for

Tags: javascript, eventos

tengo  elsiguiente codigo,

```
    for (let index = 1; index < 7; index++) {
        document.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault()
            DatosPersonas()
        })
    }
```

lo que pasa es que cuando doy  click al boton de enviar formulario, el addevenlisstener esta activo en todos los ciclos for, quisiera que escuchara cada ciclo y estuviera no activado, para que solo ejecute la funcion si le doy click al boton,  como lo haria, gracias.

Comment: la pregunta es porque pondrias el eventListener en un for cuando solo queres agregarlo a un elemento (en este caso el formulario)

Comment: porque necesito que se ejecute la funcion cada vez que se da submit

Comment: no necesitas el for amigo, en este caso necesitas agregar el evento a un solo elemento (el form), el for lo necesitarías en caso de estar recorriendo una coleccion de elementos y quisieras agregar un eventListener a cada uno de ellos, como una serie de div's

Comment: entiendo, aunque necesitaba llenar varias veces el mismo formulario, y  capturar datos, por eso escuho el evento submit

Comment: si es así agrega más detalles a tu pregunta aclarando específicamente el comportamiento que buscas en tu página web y agregando el resto del código (si es necesario para que los demás puedan probarlo) así tu pregunta cobra algo más de sentido para nosotros. De todas formas la función asociada al evento se ejecutara cada vez que envíes los datos del formulario.

Comment: es posible que lo que necesites sea esto:  **document.addEventListener( "submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    for( let index = 1; index < 7; index++ ) {
        DatosPersonas();
    }
});** ?

Comment: lo  que se busca es que el formulario se llene 6 veces y  se envie seis veces y  se capture los datos de cada enviada cada vez que se daclick en enviar

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, no necesitas asignar la escucha de eventos cada vez, dado que el formulario es el mismo. Si quieres recoger cada dato que se escribe en ese formulario, puedes crear un array e ir metiendo en ese array los datos.

Por ejemplo aquí, en `allData` se irán guardando los diferentes valores del formulario:

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
var allData = [];

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(myForm);
  e.target.reset();
  allData.push(formData);
  allData.forEach(function(item, i) {
    console.log('Entrada %d: \n', i + 1);
    for (const pair of item.entries()) {
      console.log(`${pair[0]}, ${pair[1]}`);
    }
    console.log('\n');
  });
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label>Nombre: <input type="text"  name="name"/></label>
  <br /><br />
  <label>Apellido: <input type="text"  name="lastname"/></label>
  <br /><br />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

De todos modos, lo que intentas hacer no es lo habitual, lo propio sería crear un formulario que recoja todos los datos que se necesitan una vez estén todos cumplimentados.

Otra idea que se podría ocurrir sería tener varios formularios, y asignar eventos de escucha a todos ellos. Esto también es posible, puedes alcanzarlos con `querySelectorAll` por el tipo `form`, o por una clase y asignar el evento de escucha (esta vez sí asignarías el listener usando un bucle), pero tampoco es una práctica habitual. Casi siempre se tiene un sólo formulario donde se recoge todo lo necesario. Y puedes usar por ejemplo [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) para hacer secciones en ese mismo formulario.